# How resolve right guava for selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, maven-surefire-plugin

I know there are few similar questions, but they are mostly outdated and does not help to resolve my problem.

Using Selenium: 4.0.0-alpha-3 (tried with 3.141.59 had the same issue) and apache surefire: 3.0.0-M3

Guava dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edgehtml-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-xpi-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |     \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chromium-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-http:jar:4.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO]       \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

When creating new ChromeDriver getting the exception bellow, but if I remove surefire dependency from the pox.xml everything runs.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;

    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ExecutableFinder.<clinit>(ExecutableFinder.java:33)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:105)
    at com.swx.ptp.ctest.gui.CnsSample.webCnsOpen(CnsSample.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I've tried inserting latest guava dependency, but without any success.

```
System.out.println(com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.class.getResource("ImmutableSet.class"));
jar:file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/google/code/google-collections/google-collect/snapshot-20080530/google-collect-snapshot-20080530.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading maven surefire to v2.22.2 from v3.0.0-M3 solved the problem